# Prevent an onClick event on a span element when it was clicked once

Tags: reactjs, disable, use-ref

I'm building a game where you have to click on a cross pictogram or check pictogram depending on whether the answer were correct or false. But as soons as you have answered you can't click again on none of the two pictograms (even on the one you didn't click on).

In order to do this, I used useRef on the element that contains the pictograms and I tried to make the element disabled. It didn't work.
I've also tried to make their parent element "uneventable" but it didn't work neither

I would appreciate any help. thank you

```
const pictoAnswer = useRef()
const divParent = useRef()

pictoAnswer.current.disabled = true
divParent.current.pointerEvents = "none"
```

overall view

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

// modules
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCheck, faTimes } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const WordList = () => {
  const liBgColor = useRef();
  const pictoAnswer = useRef();
  const divParent = useRef();

  // change the color bg of the list element
  const isCorrect = (answer) => {
    if (answer) {
      liBgColor.current.style.backgroundColor = "#5DCF36";
    } else {
      liBgColor.current.style.backgroundColor = "#d15f5f";
    }
  };

  //list of word to make guess
  let wordsToGuess = ["chambre", "salon", "rire", "fusée"];
  const numberOfWordToGuess = wordsToGuess.length;

  const [indexWord, setIndexWord] = useState(1);
  console.log("indexWord:", indexWord);
  const [wordToDisplay, setWordToDisplay] = useState([wordsToGuess[0]]);

 
  // push the next word to guess into the wordToDisplay array
  const handleAnswer = (answer) => {
   

    pictoAnswer.current.disabled = true;
    divParent.current.pointerEvents = "none";
    //set the new index of the word item
    setIndexWord(indexWord + 1);
    //change the bgColor depending on the answer
    isCorrect(answer);
    //would display the next word or not
    if (indexWord == numberOfWordToGuess || indexWord > numberOfWordToGuess) {
      console.log("no more word to guess");
    } else {
      setWordToDisplay([...wordToDisplay, wordsToGuess[indexWord]]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ul className="word__list">
      {wordToDisplay.map((word, i) => (
        <li key={i} className="word__item" ref={liBgColor}>
          <p className="word">{word}</p>
          <div className="icon-box" ref={divParent}>
            <span
              ref={pictoAnswer}
              onClick={() => {
                handleAnswer(false);
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} color={"#FF5252"} />
            </span>
            <span
              ref={pictoAnswer}
              onClick={() => {
                handleAnswer(true);
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} color={"#008000"} />
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default WordList;
```

[codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-dubinsky-39doy)

Comment: document.querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; }, {once : true});

Comment: There's not enough information to know for sure, but you should at least check that the components with the pictures are not being unmounted and remounted because that will reset its disabled/enabled state.

Comment: Instead of preventing further clicks to register you should just not pass any onClick handler if it is answered, so clicking will not do anything. Alternatively you could check the answered state in the handler and bail out of any further actions if it is true.

Comment: Why aren't you using semantic buttons (with `disabled` attribute)? Your React ref usage appears to be incorrect as only the last mapped `word` element gets attached ref, you even assign `pictoAnswer` ref twice in the same render(!!). `indexWord` won't be the incremented value in `handleAnswer`, but maybe this is ok (*???*) though I suspect not since you later try to push a new word to display with `wordsToGuess[indexWord]`. Seems a mis-use of React refs when you should be using `className` or `style` to set any style (versus DOM manipulation).

Comment: Can you create a ***running*** codesandbox for this code so we've a bit better context on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DrewReese there is https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-dubinsky-39doy

Comment: Also, you'll notice strange state changes due to your use of index as key `key={i}`, instead use a unique property of each mapped item (in this case you only have `word`, but they seem to be unique?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is incorrect use of React refs to manipulate DOM elements.

## Solution

1. Store a "settled" state array initialized to null values to indicate if a word has been marked true/false. Same condition is used to prevent further "click" handling.
2. Use CSS to style the list item.
3. Update `handleAnswer` to set the "settled" state and increment the word index.
4. Use an `useEffect` hook to update the words to display.

Code:

```
const wordsToGuess = ["chambre", "salon", "rire", "fusée"];

const App = () => {
  const [indexWord, setIndexWord] = useState(0);
  const [wordToDisplay, setWordToDisplay] = useState([]);
  const [settled, setSettled] = useState(Array(wordsToGuess.length).fill(null));

  useEffect(() => {
    setWordToDisplay(wordsToGuess.slice(0, indexWord + 1));
  }, [indexWord]);

  const handleAnswer = (index, answer) => () => {
    if (settled[index] === null) {
      setSettled((settled) =>
        settled.map((el, i) => (i === indexWord ? answer : el))
      );
      if (indexWord < wordsToGuess.length - 1) setIndexWord((i) => i + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ul className="word__list">
      {wordToDisplay.map((word, i) => (
        <li
          key={i}
          className={classNames("word__item", {
            "settled-true": settled[i] === true,
            "settled-false": settled[i] === false
          })}
        >
          <p className="word">{word}</p>
          <div className="icon-box">
            <span onClick={handleAnswer(i, false)}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} color={"#FF5252"} />
            </span>
            <span onClick={handleAnswer(i, true)}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} color={"#008000"} />
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

CSS:

```
.settled-true {
  background-color: #5dcf36;
}

.settled-false {
  background-color: #d15f5f;
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit prevent-an-onclick-event-on-a-span-element-when-it-was-clicked-once]